# How to remove bandwidthd 32 bit from 64 bit Xubuntu

Tags: apt, software-center, 64-bit, xubuntu, 32-bit

i downloaded [bandwidthd](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/bandwidthd/bandwidthd/bandwidthd%202.0.1/SARGE-bandwidthd_2.0.1_i386.deb?r=http://sourceforge.net/projects/bandwidthd/files/&ts=1354243054&use_mirror=nchc) from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bandwidthd/files/latest/download) and tried to install it using Ubuntu Software Center.

It failed,  but still it breaks my Xubuntu. Later i found that it is for 32 bit while mine is 64 bit system. Now apt-get no longer working because it stuck with bandwidthd error.

apt-get remove bandwidth, resulted in error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  bandwidthd:i386 :
>   Depends: ucf:i386 but it is not installable

sudo apt-get -f install, error:

> ```
>  sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
>     dpkg: error processing bandwidthd:i386 (--remove):
>      Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
>      reinstall it before attempting a removal.
>     Errors were encountered while processing:
>      bandwidthd:i386
> ```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED using tips from [ptheo](https://askubuntu.com/a/182872/85510):

```
sudo -H gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

then remove all segments mentioning the culprit.