# resolve broken apt-get package download

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, kubuntu, ppa

I got an issue with the *leap-keymanager* package.

```
sudo apt-get purge leap-keymanager 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python-leap-common needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Which is preventing me from doing a dist upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python-leap-common needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

How can I fix this? I've add the [leapcode PPA](https://launchpad.net/~leapcode/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and done `sudo apt-get update` but I still get the same message.

```
python --version Python 2.7.9
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid
```

Comment: have you tryed `sudo apt-get install -f` ?

Comment: Yes. I get `E: The package python-leap-common needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Comment: have you tried to remove `python-leap-common`

Comment: @Neil I just removed python-leap-common from /var/lib/dpkg/status and it seems to be working. Give me a minute and I'll see if I can confirm.

Comment: @Neil yes, it is working! Thanks. At least I don't get any error messages about `python-leap-common` but when I try to upgrade I get a **Cannot upgrade** - Please fix the '/usr/bin/python' symlink. I change the symlink because I had a script that depended on python3 but I changed it back. Need to look into what I need to do now...

Comment: I found a solution to the latter issue here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/448926/do-release-upgrade-python-install-is-corrupted Doing `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python` solved my python symlink issue.

Comment: Do you want me to post removing  `python-leap-common` as an answer ?

Comment: The important part about removing `python-leap-common` from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is to **remove the whole block of information about it** as written here: askubuntu.com/questions/146150/unable-to-fix-broken-packages-with-sudo-apt-get-install-f#answer-182872

Comment: Yes with the information about the whole block. I was hesitant to fiddle with the status file without being sure what exactly to remove. I will approve your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `python-leap-common`

```
sudo apt-get remove python-leap-common
```

The important part about removing `python-leap-common` from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is to remove the whole block of information about it. [Refer here ...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146150/unable-to-fix-broken-packages-with-sudo-apt-get-i%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bnstall-f#answer-182872)

Comment: Unfortunately `sudo apt-get remove leap-keymanager` didn't work. I had to remove the package from `/var/lib/dpkg/status`