# fixing broken packages in ubuntu : repost

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql

I have a lot of broken packages in my ubuntu 14.04 distro, which I am trying to fix.

I am following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/182872/415350) answer by one of our community member. I followed the first two commands and after editing the file which he has mentioned I am not sure how can I determine which are the packages are broken and which one's to be removed.

When I am running `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` I am getting that broken packages issue.

Here's the result of running above command

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 10.0.25+maria-1~trusty is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Issue could be that I already have `mariadb` installed, although I am not sure how it got installed. I tried to remove it using the `synaptic package manager` but that didn't help.

Can someone please help me with that.I can share the chunk of that file If needed.

Comment: Include the output of your command `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` .

Comment: check the updated question @ThorOdinson

Comment: @ThorOdinson The OP updated the question.

Comment: @mchid You see what we face as a starter. No replies and later it gets lost without any help/suggestion.

Comment: I've been trying numerous things and have tried numerous answers. If I put them as a list, someone might call "TOO MUCH INFO".

BTW, yes I tried removing the mariadb from the synaptic package manager as I read the same in some thread. that didn't help either.

Comment: Look, if there is too much info, people like me can always edit it out. If there's not enough info, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I am working on a rails app. that has mysql. I don't know when and how this mariadb got installed. I don't know about it.

Updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39838/discussion-between-suraj-and-mchid).

Comment: As for the other problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120185/couldnt-create-database-for-rails-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what we have so far.

First, edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and remove mariadb by executing the following commands:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^.*mariadb.*$//g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, let's fix that broken package:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient18=5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 libmysqlclient-dev
```

Please post any more errors, thanks.

Comment: This works like a charm. So `Mariadb` was causing the problems for me